# How do I recognize if PHP is installed as Module or CGI

Tags: php, configuration, cgi

how do I know excactly if PHP is used as module in Apache or used as CGI? Which configuration param is telling me this in phpinfo() ???

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo PHP_SAPI;
echo php_sapi_name();
```

[`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/php-sapi-name)

If you prefer `phpinfo()` (or its cli equivalent `php -i`) you should find a property `Server API` on the top. Because you want to know, what handler your apache uses `php -i` is not an option for you.